# Error 1054: Unknown column 'ProductName' in 'having clause'

Tags: mysql, go, having

My sql Query is

```
Select id, 
       prodPre, 
       prodNo, 
       ProdPost, 
       concat(IFNULL(prodPre,""),prodNo,IFNULL(ProdPost, "")) as ProductName from products
having ProductName like '%foo%'
```

this query produces the following error when I run it through golang

> Error 1054: Unknown column 'ProductName' in 'having clause'

but it works fine when I run the query directly against the database.

I'm running MySQL 5.7.31

Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: does it work if to write: `having concat(IFNULL(prodPre,""),prodNo,IFNULL(ProdPost, "")) like '%foo'` ?

Comment: There is no aggregation here. Is there a particular reason for the Having clause? The sql I see should just use a Where clause.

Comment: The published query is missing a FROM clause...BTW the error I get is ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

This worked when I modified the query to this

```
Select id, 
       prodPre, 
       prodNo, 
       ProdPost from products
where concat(IFNULL(prodPre,""),prodNo,IFNULL(ProdPost, "")) like '%foo%'
```

I want to thank @serge-v and @maru for your advice.